# Get count of occurrence of certain value in DataTable column

Tags: c#, datatable

I am creating a DataTable dynamically, NOT from SQL. I need to count the number of times the value of '0' appears in the 'testresult' column. So far everything I've tried returns a count of 0, even though the table has 1 entry of '0' in the testresult column. HELP! :)

I've tried:

1)

```
DataRow[] rows = dtMerged.Select("testresult Like '%0%'");
            int rowcount = rows.Length;
```

2. 

```
int rowcount = dtMerged.Select("testresult = 0").Count();
```

3. 

```
int rowcount = Convert.ToInt32(dtMerged.Compute("Count(testresult)", "testresult Like '%0%'"));
```

4. 

```
    var rowcount = dtMerged.AsEnumerable()
                    .GroupBy(r => r.Field<string>("testresult"))
                    .Select(r => new 
                            { 
                                Str = r.Key, 
                                Count = r.Count() 
                            });
```

All of these options give me a rowcount of '0' except number 4, which resulted in a value of 'null'. Here is an image of the DataTable in question.

[image]

Thanks!

Here is a sample of code that will create essentially the same DataTable that I'm working with, my creation method is a bit complicated for copy/pasting:

```
    DataTable dtMerged= new DataTable();
    dtMerged.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
    dtMerged.Columns.Add("hbserial", typeof(string));
    dtMerged.Columns.Add("testresult", typeof(string));
            
    dtMerged.Rows.Add(0, "testhashboard1", "1");
    dtMerged.Rows.Add(1, "samplehashboard1", "1");
    dtMerged.Rows.Add(2, "samplehashboard2", "0");
    return dtMerged;
    
    //Attempt 1
    DataRow[] rows = dtMerged.Select("testresult Like '%0%'");
                        int rowcount = rows.Length;
    //Attempt 2    
    int rowcount = dtMerged.Select("testresult = 0").Count();
    
    //Attempt 3    
    int rowcount = Convert.ToInt32(dtMerged.Compute("Count(testresult)", "testresult Like '%0%'"));
    
    //Attempt 4    
    var rowcount = dtMerged.AsEnumerable()
                                .GroupBy(r => r.Field<string>("testresult"))
                                .Select(r => new 
                                        { 
                                            Str = r.Key, 
                                            Count = r.Count() 
                                        });
```

Comment: Please update your [mcve] to include all of your efforts so far. We want a single code block to copy and paste in.

Comment: Attempt 1 returned 1, as did Attempts 2 and 3. I am not sure I see the issue.

Comment: Ok, very odd. I've been fighting with this all morning. Let me give it another look and make sure I'm not missing something. Thanks!

Comment: SMH, it's working! Thanks for your time and I'm sorry it was wasted. :(